# Attaching Events To Elements

Tags: jquery

I've got two textboxes that load some data. What I would like to do is, after selecting an element from the first box, filter the 2nd box with the value selected from the first one.
I tried doing it this way but it never entered the function:

```
$('input[id$=r_Client]').live('result', function() {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var terminal = tr.find('input[id$=r_Service]');
            var selected = $('input[id$=r_Client]').val();
            var url = '<%= Url.Action("Refex","Services",new {Id="-l-"}) %>'.replace('-l-', selected);
            $(terminal).flushCache().setOptions({ url: url });
        });
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[id$=r_Client]').live('change', function() {
            //your code
        });
```

Comment: I've already tried it your way but it still didn't work. What else can I do?